# Explicit URL with tab=newest and tagnames= behavior change

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

I have been using URLs of the form

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=newest&tagnames=xslt+or+java

to read recent questions for specific tags.  About 3 hours ago this stopped working... it returns the same set of results each time now, with the most recent item being about 3 hours old, instead of updating to show more recent posts.

Is this change deliberate?

Comment: I can confirm something is odd there ... looking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That page is one of the last spots we still use SQL Server FTS, one of the many reasons we migrated off it is that it **randomly** decides to stop updating.

I am kicking off a rebuild at the moment and the lists should start updating again.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now, thanks.