# Query result not refreshed in last several hrs

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicit URL with tab=newest and tagnames= behavior change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121856/explicit-url-with-tab-newest-and-tagnames-behavior-change)

This seems to be similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88049/query-result-not-refreshed-in-last-3-hrs)

[Unanswered C# Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23?tab=newest) - top question was modified 4 hrs ago
[Unanswered jQuery Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/jQuery?tab=newest) - top question was modified 5 hrs ago
[Unanswered Javascript Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript?tab=newest) - top question was modified 4 hrs ago
[Unanswered SQL Server Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/sql-server?tab=newest) - top question was modified 1 hr ago

There are newer unanswered questions in all these tags. I get same results in FF, IE and Chrome. I am at "newest" tab.

Also checked with a few web proxies (both in US and Europe) and I get the same results so it is not limited to my location.

Comment: You actually aren't on the newest tab - you're on **unanswered newest**. Going to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 Brings up brand new questions for me

Comment: @SimonSheehan, when you go to your link, it shows unanswered questions that are hours newer than the OP's link and should show there but don't.  His big is valid.

Comment: @Simon, the tab is saved, probably in cookie, so I did not have it in the link but I have since updated the links that would take to "unanswered newest". Can you reproduce it?